# Почему EAP не быстрее APM?

Tags: c#, .net, сеть, сокет

Здравствуйте.

Моё клиент-серверное приложение написанное на языке C# использует для асинхронной передачи по сети модель [APM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) "обёрнутую" в async/await с помощью метода FromAsync класса TaskFactory. Данный подход меня вполне устраивает, но на MSDN я прочитал, что асинхронная работа с сокетами посредством другой модели - [EAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx) - быстрее и что данная модель рекомендуется для высокопроизводительного кода.

Прочитав, решил проверить, так ли это и написал два теста, в одном из которых тестировалась APM + async/await, а в другом - EAP без каких-либо обёрток. Оказалось, что APM лишь ненамного медленее EAP, а в некоторых случаях (при передаче больших пакетов данных более 1 Мб за раз), даже быстрее. Замеры делал с помощью библиотеки BenchmarkDotNet.

Может быть и вовсе не стоит ждать от EAP какой-то особенной производительности? Объекты SocketAsyncEventArgs для приёма и передачи данных создаю лишь раз, и использую их потом всё время пока работает тест. Память под массивы для передачи и приёма выделяю во время теста, но точно также делаю и в тесте для APM. В конце теста EAP пересоздаю объект TaskCompletionSource и так происходит, соответственно, при каждом тестовом прогоне. Но не думаю, что создание одного объекта TaskCompletionSource может как-то повлиять на результат.

Предполагал, что "голый" EAP будет обязательно быстрее APM с async/await хотя бы по причине отсутствия инфраструктуры конечного автомата сопрограмм и связанных с ним накладных расходов. Но оказалось, что модель, которая по утверждениям MSDN должна работать медленее, работает быстрее кода, который по утверждениям все того же MSDN должен работать быстрее. Причём код безо всякого синтаксического сахара. Но работает медленнее.

Так и должно быть или я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: Если не секрет, то где именно вы прочитали что EAP быстрее?

Comment: Прочитал [вот тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs(v=vs.110).aspx). Цитата: _Этот класс был специально разработан для сетевых серверных приложений, которым нужна высокая производительность.
Главной особенностью этих расширений является избежание повторных размещений и синхронизация объектов во время асинхронных операций ввода-вывода большого объема. Шаблон разработки Begin и End, реализованный в настоящее время System.Net.Sockets.Socket класс требует System.IAsyncResult выделить объект для каждой асинхронной операции сокета._

Comment: это просто класс, объект которого можно повторно использовать. разница, если она вообще будет, будет заметна только на серверных приложениях, с ручной работой с сокетами и *очень* большим количеством операций (много маленьких операций, а не одна большая, на которой вы меряли). Там не утверждается, что EAP быстрее или медленее APM, просто упоминается что существуют специфические оптимизации для специфических случаев, с которым вы скорее всего не столкнетесь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но... у меня как раз ручная работа с сокетами и серверное приложение, т.е. клиент и сервер. Я производил замеры следующим образом: передавал в цикле пакеты определенного размера (8 Кб, 1Мб, 2Мб) некоторое количество раз (1, 100, 1000). Плюс сам BenchmarkDotNet запускал тесты опредлённое количество раз. Думаю, что количество операций было большим. А насчёт размера... Вы имеете ввиду, небольшой размер пакета отправляемого за раз? Вот как раз в этом случае EAP был быстрее. В целом, Вы бы рекомендовали отказаться от APM в пользу EAP?